# Conditional Html attribute using razor @html helpers

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm trying to add a disable attribute to the html that is generated via @html helper functions but can't seem to get something working that works in the attrib parameters of the html helper.  what i have below will still write disabled for the html... but i can't remove it cause then the helper doesn't work.

i have a variable defined:

```
@{ var displayItem = (Model.TypeId == 100) }

@Html.TextBox("listitem", "", new {@class = "form-control", @disabled = (@displayItem ? "" : "disabled")})
```

but because i have to list the parameter @disabled, that produces html like this:

```
<input class="form-control"  disabled="" id="listitem" name="listitem"  type="text" value="" />
```

because disabled is listed it disables the input.  but the html helper doesn't work unless i give it a parameter name.

How to write the disabled in the parameter list so that disabled doesn't show at all if it's not supposed to be disabled?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
@{ var displayItem = (Model.TypeId == 100) }
@Html.TextBox("listitem", "", displayItem ? (object)new { @class = "form-control", disabled = "disabled" } : (object)new { @class = "form-control"});
```

or

```
@{
    var attributes = Model.TypeId == 100 ? (object)new { @class = "form-control", disabled = "disabled" } : (object)new { @class = "form-control"});
}
@Html.TextBox("listitem", "", attributes)
```

or a simple `if` block

```
@(if Model.TypeId == 100)
{
    @Html.TextBox("listitem", "", new {@class = "form-control", disabled = "disabled" })
}
else
{
    @Html.TextBox("listitem", "", new {@class = "form-control" })
}
```

Note that the value of disabled controls are not submitted, so a `readonly` attribute may be more appropriate

Comment: ok, i was wondering if there was some other trick to doing the construction of the attribute parameter, but i guess not.  Tx.

Answer (score 3):

You also can use a Dictionary<string, object> and pass that to the html helper:

```
@{
    var attributes = new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        { "class", "form-control" }
    };

    if (Model.TypeId == 100)
    {
        attributes.Add("disabled", "disabled");
    }
}

@Html.TextBox("listitem", "", attributes)
```

Comment: This is the most correct way in my opinion. The htmlAttributes parameter for HtmlHelpers can be either object or IDictionary<string, object>