# Unable to assign lambda expression on front end to decide if a field is required or not

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to make a form where the form is required *only* if a field of another model is set. When trying to do the following:

```
@model MyApp.ViewModels.ModelVM
...
@Html.Label("Tickets", new { @class = "control-label" })
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FooBar,
     new
     {
     @class = "form-control",
     @required = (model => model.Foo == 1 ? true : false),
     })
```

I get the compiler error "Cannot assign lambda expression to anonymous type"

How can I get the result I want?

Comment: Are you sure you want lambda there and not just `@required = Model.Foo == 1 ? true : false` which accesses the current instance of the `Model`?

Comment: You even don't need ternary operator. `@requered = Model.Foo == 1` do the same.

Comment: Use conditional validation attributes (e.g. a [Foolproof](https://github.com/leniel/foolproof) `[RequiredIf]` attribute applied to `FooBar`) - `required` is HTML5 client side only, and wont even work if you have enabled mvc's cleint side validation

Answer (score 0):

An excerpt from Microsoft docs regarding anonymous types and exception you've had:
   " Anonymous types contain one or more public 
    read-only properties...The expression that is used 
    to initialize a property cannot be null, **an 
    anonymous function**, or a pointer type."

Using only the check to initialize the property should do the trick.

```
@required = model.Foo == 1
```

Comment: The ternary operator is not needed.  `==` already returns a boolean.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use lambda expression to the anonymous type inside HTML helper (i.e. `htmlAttributes`). To use conditional `required` attribute as HTML attribute, you can do it using ternary operator like this:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FooBar, Model.Foo == 1 ? 
     (object)new { @class = "form-control", @required = "required" } :
     (object)new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Or using an `if` block:

```
@if (Model.Foo == 1)
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FooBar, new { @class = "form-control", @required = "required" })
}
else
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FooBar, new { @class = "form-control" })
}
```

**Note:** `required` HTML attribute for `<input>` elements is a [boolean attribute](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#boolean-attribute), which `false` value is indicated by absence of the attribute, and the presence of that attribute simply indicates `true` value:

> The values "true" and "false" are *not allowed* on boolean attributes.
>   To represent a false value, the attribute has to be omitted
>   altogether.

Related issue:

[Conditional Html attribute using razor @html helpers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45624008/conditional-html-attribute-using-razor-html-helpers)